# Why a message always appears in Tweeter: Sorry! We did something wrong

Tags: twitter

Please help. How can I fix this problem? 
I can't tweet anything at my company's page in Twitter - always see the message  Sorry! We did something wrong

Comment: What is the full message?

Comment: it is the full one.  Sorry! We did something wrong.